# centering div behind other divs- padding & margin not working

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

`#home-slider` should be perfectly centered behind all other divs within `#home`. `margin` and `padding` don't seem to work, as  `#home-slider` remains at the top, left side of it's parent div. How else can I bring it down and centered? Or rather, what have I missed?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dsZSE/11/)

[live site](http://frshstudio.com)

html

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div id="home">
                <div id="home-slider">              
                     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/840/420" alt="home-slider" />
                 </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/232/232" alt="logo" id="logo" /></a></h1>
            </div><!-- end logo -->

            <div id="slider_mask">
                <div class="slide_container">
                    <div class="slide"><p>is where creative <i>je ne sais quoi</i> + business savvy collide.</p></div>
                    <div class="slide"><p>is the maker + doer for makers + doers</p></div>
                    <div class="slide">
                        <ul>
                        <li>No items.</li>                  </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="left_button"><a href="#" class="left-arrow" title="left arrow"></a></div>
                <div class="right_button"><a href="#" class="right-arrow" title="right arrow"></a></div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- end home -->
```

css

```
#home-slider {
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-9999;
}

#home .logo {
    padding-top: 215px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 232px;
}

#home #slider_mask {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 60px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#home #slider_mask .left_button {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 23px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(img/left-arrow.png);
    text-indent: -99999px;
}

#home #slider_mask .left_button:hover {
    background: url(img/left-arrow-hover.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#home #slider_mask .slide_container {
    float: left;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}

#home #slider_mask .right_button {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: 23px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(img/right-arrow.png);
    text-indent: -99999px;
}

#home #slider_mask .right_button:hover {
    background: url(img/right-arrow-hover.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#home #slider_mask .slide {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: your code in a jsfiddle, talks a bit more :) http://jsfiddle.net/NpuXc/

Comment: Is this different from your last question?

Comment: @j08691 It is. My previous question asked about pushing the home-slider behind all others, whereas this inquires about centering it on the page.

Comment: @GCyrillus there is a jsfiddle link located just above where I pasted my code in the question :)

Comment: i'm blind. time to refresh myself ...

Answer (score 1):

It's because you had inline stylings on the HTML element defining the `#home-slider` div as having a `relative` position whilst in your CSS you had it set as `absolute` positioning. The inline had overrided the external stylesheet stylings

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsZSE/10/

This is what your `#home-slider` code should look like:

```
#home-slider{
top:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/g/840/420');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
position:fixed;
z-index:-9999;
}
```

Comment: With the inline stylings removed from the HTML, and your corrected css used, the `#home-slider` is still forced to the top of it's parent div.

Also, is there reason for both `position:absolute` and `position:fixed`?

Comment: No sorry that was a mistake, use fixed as it keeps the div fixed - you don't want absolute positioning in my example. I've updated the fiddle link with the correct solution

Comment: Hm, the edited css forced `#home-slider` back to the upper left.
I've taken my site off maintenance mode so you can view what's going on first hand here- http://frshstudio.com

Comment: @AMC Hi sorry I wasn't able to get back to you earlier, I was out at the pub, can you re-up the page as I'm currently seeing a maintence page.

Comment: @AMC - are you trying to achieve something like this: http://roadworkers.org/ ? Full screen background slider?

Answer (score 1):

I understood you want `#home-slider` behind all others, and the others centered. Like adaam says "inline stylings on the HTML element defining the `#home-slider` div as having a relative position whilst in your CSS you had it set as absolute positioning. The inline had overrided the external stylesheet stylings"

I also added a few other css attributes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8t32K/).

the HTML should be:

```
<div id="home-slider">               
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/840/420" alt="home-slider" />
</div>
```

Comment: With the inline stylings removed from the HTML, and your corrected css used, the #home-slider is still forced to the top of it's parent div.